# Dropdown menu with reactjs and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

Im having a hard time figuring out how to get this dropdown to actually work.  The button renders fine, but does not drop down.  Any ideas on what I am missing here? Pretty sure i need an onClick function but not sure what to control to get it to dropdown.

```
var Dropdownbutton = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Dropdownbutton',
render: function() {
    return el.div(null,
      el.div({className: 'col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'},
        el.div({className:'btn-group'},
          el.a({href:'#',className:'btn btn-primary'},'Primary'),
          el.a({href:'#',className:'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle":'dropdown'},el.span({className:'caret'},'')),
          el.ul({className:'dropdown-menu'},
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Action')),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Another action')),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Something else here')),
            el.li({className:'divider'},''),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Separated link'))
          )
        )
      )
    );
}

});
```

Comment: You might find [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) immensely helpful.

Comment: Been going over react-bootstrap, not sure what i'm missing.  Normal buttons are no problem for me but the drop downs just don't want to work.

Comment: You are right in that you need an onClick handler.  [this file](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Dropdown.js) in particular shows react-bootstrap's approach.  Basically, I believe the onClick handler needs to add the open class to the thing that contains the dropdown (the one with the "btn-group" class).  Sorry I can't give you a full example.  At best I could show you how to do it with react-bootstrap.

Comment: A full example would require you to keep open in a state somewhere along the way so that you know whether to open or close the dropdown. You could of course just register it using the jquery plugin Bootstrap provides I believe, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can infer you don't have a division with class **dropdown**. Making a slight change to your code should work.

```
var Dropdownbutton = React.createClass({
displayName: 'Dropdownbutton',
render: function() {
    return el.div(null,
      el.div({className: 'dropdown col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'},
        el.div({className:'btn-group'},
          el.a({href:'#',className:'btn btn-primary'},'Primary'),
          el.a({href:'#',className:'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle', "data-toggle":'dropdown'},el.span({className:'caret'},'')),
          el.ul({className:'dropdown-menu'},
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Action')),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Another action')),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Something else here')),
            el.li({className:'divider'},''),
            el.li(null,el.a({href:'#'},'Separated link'))
          )
        )
      )
    );
}

});
```